# I would've done it tomorrow or I would do it tomorrow

Tags: past-tense, conditionals

which of the following sentences is correct

1.I would've done it tomorrow if I had school
2.I would do it tomorrow if I had school

I think the second sentence is grammatically correct because you use would've in the past more the second one doesn't sound right for some reason.

Comment: This shouldn't have been migrated. This is a perfectly reasonable question for a native speaker to ask. This is about the irrealis mood. The sentence contains a potentially true outcome that is couterindicated by how we interpret the conditional clause. If I hadn't commented tonight, I would have done tomorrow.

Comment: The second sentence is tricky. It doesn't carry the same weight of counterfactual probability. It starts out as an indicative conditional, but then it ought have *have*, not  *had*, in most dialects to finish properly. *Had* constitutes backshifting in this case. I do believe it is used by some to mean "I would do it tomorrow if I were to have school.

Answer (score 1):

**which of the following sentences is correct**

1.I would've done it tomorrow if I had school.
**This suggest that you will be unable to do "IT".**

2.I would do it tomorrow if I had school.
**This suggests that you could do "IT"**

In fact in this case, there is only one correct answer, first you must verify which answer is actually correct before you can contemplate which if any, are grammatically correct.

You could not do it tomorrow as there is no school so **Answer 2 is incorrect**, regardless of grammar.

The statement I would **have done** "it" tomorrow if I had, **had** school. Would have been a better answer as it suggests that you wanted to do "IT" but were unable too.

Answer (score 0):

> I would've done it 'yesterday' if I had school/classes.
>
> I would do it tomorrow if I go to school/there's school/there's no holiday for
> school.

The above two sentences are correct.